# Centering an image in the middle of the page

Tags: javascript, html, image, centering

Can somebody explain me why this code does not work. Browser respond with the value vspace="0". This means that the arithmetic expression is not correct, but why?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function resizeImage()
{
var window_height = document.body.clientHeight
var window_width  = document.body.clientWidth
var image_width   = document.images[0].width
var image_height  = document.images[0].height
var height_ratio  = image_height / window_height
var width_ratio   = image_width / window_width
var aspect_ratio  = image_height / image_width


if (height_ratio > width_ratio)
{
    document.images[0].style.width  = "auto";
    document.images[0].style.height = "100%";
}
else
{
    var new_vspace = Math.round((window_height - window_width*aspect_ratio) /    2);
    document.images[0].style.width  = "100%";
    document.images[0].style.height = "auto";
    document.images[0].vspace="new_vspace";
}
}

</script>
</head>

<BODY bgcolor=#000000 onresize="resizeImage()">

<script>
document.write('<center><img onload="resizeImage()" margin="0" border="0"     src="nweshow/picture-0011.jpg"/></center>')
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Can't you just set a CSS property of the image?

Comment: Using CSS for this sort of thing is generally faster, safer, and won't lag when the window is resized.

Comment: And your code works for me. Which browser are you using?

Comment: Don't use JS, do this instead: http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Comment: Is it normal that `document.images[0].vspace="new_vspace";` the `new_vspace` is written between " "? Isn't it a var?

Comment: The CSS option does not work for me, since I have to use JS [no library] instead. The centering problem is only part of the whole story. The image shown here is just one of many, very different in aspect ratios, shown in a slideshow randomized in order and timeout. That is why I have to use js. This slideshow has to be viewed preferably full screen, not as part of a browser, nor distracted by scrollbars, browsertype, specific user preferences, etc. Ideally the viewer is focussed on the content of the image and its [random] timing, which changes every new round of the slideshow.

Comment: So far i have only tested Google chrome. This picture [0011] percectly fits in my laptop [15" screen] with no whitespace at all. However in my superwide widescreen the same picture does not fit at all, with plenty of whitespace at the bottom but none at the top. This is where vspace comes in, since for example vspace="10" adds 10 pixels both on the top and at the bottom of the picture, according to W3 schools references, and thereby automatically centering the picture vertically, in case image_width = window_width after resizing and keeping aspect. So I added this line in the "else" part.

Answer (score 0):

I've copy-pasted your code as is and made one small change.

**From this**

```
<center><img onload="resizeImage()" margin="0" border="0"     src="nweshow/picture-0011.jpg"/></center>
```

**To this**

```
<div style="text-align: center"><img onload="resizeImage()" margin="0" border="0"     src="nweshow/picture-0011.jpg"/></div>
```

Other then that your code works perfectly fine and the image resizes and centers without any issues.

**Edit:** Forgot to mention I used a Flickr image to for testing, here is the link: http://www.flickr.com/photos/23397895@N08/8729551516/in/explore-2013-05-11

Comment: To answer the last answer by adamj. The text-align option only centers the image horizontally. BTW the problem with "Stack Overflow" adding comments is that you cannot start a new line within a comment by pressing <enter> for than this key immediately adds the [unfinished] comment, so I have to be careful. This leaves the problem of centering the image vertically, in case the witdth of the image is much greater than the height: aspect ratio of the picture in question as defined in my code = .54. So there is plenty whitespace at the bottom of the screen, but none at the top. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

problem solved by adding this line to the conditional [if-part] of "resizeImage()":

document.images[0].hspace = Math.floor((window_width - image_width / height_ratio) / 2);

and adding this line to the "else" part:

document.images[0].vspace = Math.floor((window_height - image_height / width_ratio) / 2);

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to your suggestion not putting the value of vspace= within quotes [contrary to the reference of W3] I write the math-expression directly as its value [without quotes] and not binding it to a variable: add this line to the if-part of "resizeImage()":

> document.images[0].hspace = Math.floor((window_width - image_width / height_ratio) / 2);

this centers the image horizontally in case height= 100%

and also add this line to the "else" part:

> document.images[0].vspace = Math.floor((window_height - image_height / width_ratio) / 2);

this centers the image vertically in case width is resized to 100%

This looks simple enough and cannot be done by CSS.

Thanks again for your help!!